# ASP.NET Core returns 404 after resetting applicationhost.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-express

I had a bit of an issue with IIS and I couldn't run my website anymore. I managed to fix it after reinstalling IIS and removing `applicationhost.config`. Now I can launch the website from Visual Studio but if I surf to it I get:

> Not Found
>
> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

I don't see any request showing up in the logs either. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

The applicationhost.config looks like this;

```
<site name="arnvanhoutte" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\OneDrive\Apps\Web\arnvanhoutte\arnvanhoutte" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52250:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44397:localhost" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
  <siteDefaults>
    <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
  </siteDefaults>
  <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
  <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
```

This is the log after I run `iisexpress.exe /config:"applicationhost.config" /site:"arnvanhoutte" /apppool:"Clr4IntegratedAppPool"  /trace:error`

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 2060781
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 2060796
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 2060796
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 2060796
Start listenerChannel http:0
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:52250/" for site "arnvanhoutte" application "/"
Successfully registered URL "https://localhost:44397/" for site "arnvanhoutte" application "/"
Registration completed for site "arnvanhoutte"
AppPool 'Clr4IntegratedAppPool' initialized
InitComplete event signalled
IIS Express is running.
Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by adding my user to the group IIS_IUSRS